# MongoDB takes long time to query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which over 10000 documents. Each document is about 10KB.
When I run this query:

```
News
.find({topics: { '$elemMatch': { '$in': ['5606059d924327636fe3e150'] } }, state: 'APPROVED', is_removed: false})
```

it takes me around 8 seconds to finish the query.

I have used the indexes for the fields: topics, state and is_removed. The explain() query returned: "millis" : 45.

I think the result of query is quite large (10000*10KB) so it will take time to pull the data right?

Please help me to explain this and show me how to reduce the query time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For starters: Your query is unnecessarily complicated.

```
db.collection.find({
    topics:{ "$in":["5606059d924327636fe3e150","5606059d924327636fe3e151"]},
    state:"APPROVED",
    is_removed: false
})
```

Furthermore, you might want to have an index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ topics:1, state:1, is_removed:1 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to search the documents are matched one of many topics, in that case, can I query like this:


db.collection.find({
    topics::["5606059d924327636fe3e150""5606059d924327636fe3e151"],
    state:"APPROVED",
    is_removed: false
})

Comment: @hiepnv Edited accordingly.

Comment: since the topics is an array of ObjectID, the above query did not return anything. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you ***please*** post at least one sample document? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: Hi, Markus, thanks for your helps. I've solved the problem now. Regards.

Comment: @hiepnv Can you share your solution? It might help someone else.

Comment: @hiepnv share your solution please, i need help to this case. Thanks before.